# How to undo the achievement of a goal?

Tags: rules, 7

I have 2 goals on my website: 'Published 1 article' and 'Published 2 articles'. I have according rules that record the tasks for these goals when new content is published by a user.

Now, assume that a user published exactly 2 articles. That means he/she completed 'Published 2 articles'. How can I undo this goal (programmatically) when one of his/her articles are removed?

PS: I've already found [this post](https://drupal.org/node/2179139), but as there aren't any answers, it wasn't that helpful... :)

Comment: After a quick look in the code it seems it is not currently possible with the goals module. I have turned the support request you linked to into a feature request so you will have to either write a path for the module that allows it, pay someone else to write the patch, or wait until someone else does it on their own. There is not much we can do to help here on Drupal answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible yet. A request has been made [here](https://drupal.org/node/2179139). Hopefully, the maintainers will provide this feature in the future.

If someone gives a working solution later on, I'll mark it as answer instead.